# Docker Container Virtual Host SSL Configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, docker, virtualhost, http-proxy

I have the following setup and working properly (I am on Docker 1.6):

[image]

One Docker container acts as the virtual host proxy for the other web applications running in individual Docker containers. (I should add that I am not a whiz at configuring servers, or networks for that matter.)

I have been trying to add SSL to the setup, but with little success. Each container mounts the file directory on the host for the certificates. For example, to run a container once I use the following:

```
docker run -d -P --name build \
    -v /home/applications/src/ssl-cert:/etc/ssl/certs \
    -e "DBL=mysql:dbname=build;host=192.168.0.1;port=3306" \
    -e "DB_USER=foo" -e "DB_PASS=bar" \
    --link mysql56:mysql \
    --add-host dockerhost:`/sbin/ip addr | grep 'eth0' | grep 'inet' | cut -d'/' -f1 | awk '{print $2}'` \
    -p 8001:80 -p 4431:443 \
     repos/build:latest
```

If I attempt to connect to `https://build.example.com` I get certificate errors and cannot connect. The container's Apache configuration has the appropriate configuration in default-ssl.conf for the certificate files (which works if this is a stand-alone instance):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    # Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/build.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/build.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/digicert/digicertca.crt

    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I attempt to run the following for the proxy container:

```
docker run -it -d -P --name apache_proxy \
    -v /home/applications/src/ssl-cert:/etc/ssl/certs \
    -p 8000:80 -p 443:443 \
    repos/apache-proxy:latest
```

This container also contains the same default-ssl.conf.

I have tried running this in several different configurations:

- running the SSL config in the Apache proxy container only
- running the SSL config in the build application container only
- running the SSL config in both containers

If feel as if I am missing something obvious, but cannot put a finger on what it would be. Is there something I am missing when it comes to running SSL in a configuration like this?

Comment: Does apache start without any complains? What is the exact ssl error?

Comment: Apache starts and runs fin @Robert. There are no SSL errors save for the site will not run.

Comment: I want to clarify this: "I get certificate errors and cannot connect." Can you provide details of it?

Comment: I get a 503 error.

Comment: You should see further details about that 503 in the apache error log.

Comment: There are none there @Robert

Comment: 503, certificate errors, and "cannot connect" are all mutually eclusive. You need to be more specific and test with basic command-line tools.

Comment: I will do some more testing and add any information I find @covener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we want to add SSL to hosts behind a reverse proxy, we can configure the hosts three ways:

- **Edge:** The reverse proxy decrypts incoming HTTPS traffic and communicates with the backend servers over plain-text HTTP.
- **Pass-through:** The backend servers decrypt all traffic and the reverse proxy simply forwards HTTPS requests to them.
- **Hybrid:** The reverse proxy decrypts HTTPS traffic and then *re-encrypts* traffic bound for the backend servers.

The first option is the easiest to set up—we only need to install certificates and configure SSL on the reverse proxy. The second, "pass-through" approach enables the backend servers to manage their SSL configurations independently, but the reverse proxy is now "blind" because it cannot read the encrypted traffic, which we may want to do for (example) logging. We'd use the third, hybrid configuration when the proxy must read traffic but we also do not trust the network between the proxy and the backend servers.

Based on the information in the question, the first option seems the most appropriate because we trust the internal Docker network between the reverse proxy and the backend servers. We can remove the SSL configuration from the backend servers and forward requests from the reverse proxy to their standard HTTP ports.

This setup requires two additional components:

- Name-based virtual hosts configured on the proxy to forward requests for *each* backend service.
- A *single* certificate that secures *all* of the backend domain names (as multiple subjects or as a wildcard like **.example.com*).

Here's an example virtual host configuration section that we can build on:

```python
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName build.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    ProxyPass / http://build:8001/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://build:8001/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName cicd.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    ProxyPass / http://cicd:8002/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://cicd:8002/
</VirtualHost>
```

...and remember to configure the SSL directives in the *default* virtual host block. If we link the containers or run them on the same Docker network, we can use their container names as hostnames in our *httpd.conf* like shown above.

---

Speaking of networking, the question seems to indicate that we need to take a closer look at [Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) because I don't see any hints that indicate that the containers were configured to talk to each other (the 503 response status supports this assumption). The reverse proxy container must forward requests to each of the backend containers, but it cannot do so unless we [link the containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) (**deprecated**) or create an internal, [user-defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) between the containers:

```
$ docker network create build_network
$ docker run --network build_network --name apache_proxy ...
$ docker run --network build_network --name build ...
$ docker run --network build_network --name cicd ...
```

When we run containers on the same user-defined network, they can resolve the IP addresses of other containers by container name through Docker's internal DNS resolver (or by an alternate hostname if we specify the `--hostname` argument to `docker run`). Note also that because each container represents discrete host, we don't need to increment their port numbers (*8001*, *8002*, etc.). We can use port 80 to serve HTTP traffic from each container on the internal network.

```html
            +────────────────── Docker Host ─────────────────+
            │  +────────────── build_network ─────────────+  │
            │  │                                          │  │
  Client ────────────── apache_proxy (:443 → :443)        │  │
            │  │           ├── build (:80)                │  │
            │  │           └── cicd  (:80)                │  │
            │  +──────────────────────────────────────────+  │
            +────────────────────────────────────────────────+
```

Comment: Lot's of good information here Cy. I'll be back in the office later in the week and will setup and test.

Comment: On networking, `ProxyPass / http://172.17.42.1:8001` is used (for example) to pass data on the Docker network. It's "old school" and it looks like this old dog needs to learn some new tricks.

Comment: In a nutshell: upgrading Docker to take advantage of its networking capabilities and employing the basic VH directives here combined with the more explicit directives set previously will give us the proper setup to make this successful. Thanks!

Comment: @Jay Sorry about that--I misread "1.6" as "1.16"...haven't seen a 1.6 box for a while! It's probably time for an upgrade :) Glad this worked out!

Answer (score 2):

Normally if your servers run behind an apache server you would only need to configure Apache to work with SSL Certificates.
This if Apache is the only "outside" exposed server and the other servers are not directly accessible from the outside world

You would need apache to proxy to the other servers by virtue of url or port like e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName SERVERNAME_HERE

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/build.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/build.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/digicert/digicertca.crt

    # Proxy pass to other server
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://OTHER_SERVER_IP_WITHIN_DOCKER_NETWORK:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://OTHER_SERVER_IP_WITHIN_DOCKER_NETWORK:8081/

<!--Other config-->
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that helps you along...